# Manga where the mc reincarnated as some sort of a baby dragon

Tags: story-identification, manga, reincarnation

The manga is kinda similar to "Reincarnated as a dragon's egg" but the difference is the main character woke up in a forest and lived there for a few days until he was helped by some maid. (Who was also facing difficulties such as being bullied by her noble masters.)

The main character did help her but after a few chapters the main character was forced to separate with the maid girl after helping her from being burned alive because apparently he became "too dangerous" to be with the maid girl.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?  Do you recall any character names or any distinctive elements of the art or the characters?

Comment: Hello, I think it's been around 3 years ever since I last seen it. I also forgot where I read it, and the manga wasn't popular back then so not much people knows about it...

Comment: Definitely a maid, and not a hated noble daughter? Definitely burned alive and not publicly disemboweled? Were other people aware of the dragon? *Saikyou no Mamono ni Narumichi wo Tadoru Ore, Isekaijuu de Zamaa wo Shikkou suru* has several similarities, but also a lot of differences. But it's the only other child-dragon-protagonist story I've found.